# MDM Windows 10 mobile install line of business app

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, mdm

I have enrolled a Windows 10 Mobile device in MDM.
I try to install a Line of Business app as described in the documentation.

```
...........
 <Replace>
   <CmdID>2</CmdID>
   <Item>
     <Target>
       <LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/ApplicationManagement/AllowAllTrustedApps</LocURI>
     </Target>
     <Meta>
       <Format xmlns="syncml:metinf">int</Format>
       <Type xmlns="syncml:metinf">text/plain</Type>
     </Meta>
     <Data>1</Data>
   </Item>
 </Replace>
 <Add>
   <CmdID>3</CmdID>
   <Item>
     <Target>
       <LocURI>./Device/Vendor/MSFT/RootCATrustedCertificates/Root/1029F38A882AFB3B755342B08A87754C294895D1/EncodedCertificate</LocURI>
     </Target>
     <Data>MIIDEDCC.....a lot of more data....lRHvnE=</Data>
   </Item>
 </Add>
 <Add>
   <CmdID>4</CmdID>
   <Item>
     <Target>
       <LocURI>./User/Vendor/MSFT/EnterpriseModernAppManagement/AppInstallation/29B91D81-19CB-41F7-97F3-FD56D2707EE9_cg4300pk5pzh2</LocURI>
     </Target>
   </Item>
 </Add>
 <Exec>
   <CmdID>5</CmdID>
   <Item>
     <Target>
       <LocURI>./User/Vendor/MSFT/EnterpriseModernAppManagement/AppInstallation/29B91D81-19CB-41F7-97F3-FD56D2707EE9_cg4300pk5pzh2/HostedInstall</LocURI>
     </Target>
     <Meta>
       <Format xmlns="syncml:metinf">xml</Format>
     </Meta>
     <Data>&lt;Application DeploymentOptions="0" PackageUri="https://subdomain.domain.com:443/download/lobapp.appxbundle" /&gt;</Data>
   </Item>
 </Exec>
 ..........
```

The device responds with:

```
..........
 <Status>
   <CmdID>2</CmdID>
   <MsgRef>4</MsgRef>
   <CmdRef>2</CmdRef>
   <Cmd>Replace</Cmd>
   <Data>200</Data>
 </Status>
 <Status>
   <CmdID>3</CmdID>
   <MsgRef>4</MsgRef>
   <CmdRef>3</CmdRef>
   <Cmd>Add</Cmd>
   <Data>200</Data>
 </Status>
 <Status>
   <CmdID>4</CmdID>
   <MsgRef>4</MsgRef>
   <CmdRef>4</CmdRef>
   <Cmd>Add</Cmd>
   <Data>200</Data>
 </Status>
 <Status>
   <CmdID>5</CmdID>
   <MsgRef>4</MsgRef>
   <CmdRef>5</CmdRef>
   <Cmd>Exec</Cmd>
   <Data>200</Data>
 </Status>
 .........
```

So everything is fine.
Later I can see in the log from my download server that the device really downloads the lobapp.appxbundle file. But for some reason it isn't accepted.
I have tried different Mime types for the download and I have taken the Certificate from the output folder in which I created the appxbundle.
The device gives the following error:

```
..........
 <Results>
   <CmdID>11</CmdID>
   <MsgRef>1</MsgRef>
   <CmdRef>11</CmdRef>
   <Item>
     <Source>
       <LocURI>./User/Vendor/MSFT/EnterpriseModernAppManagement/AppInstallation/29B91D81-19CB-41F7-97F3-FD56D2707EE9_cg4300pk5pzh2/LastError</LocURI>
     </Source>
     <Meta>
       <Format xmlns="syncml:metinf">int</Format>
     </Meta>
     <Data>-2147009296</Data>
   </Item>
 </Results>
 <Results>
   <CmdID>13</CmdID>
   <MsgRef>1</MsgRef>
   <CmdRef>12</CmdRef>
   <Item>
     <Source>
       <LocURI>./User/Vendor/MSFT/EnterpriseModernAppManagement/AppInstallation/29B91D81-19CB-41F7-97F3-FD56D2707EE9_cg4300pk5pzh2/LastErrorDesc</LocURI>
     </Source>
     <Data>error 0x8020001B: Opening the package from location lobApp.appxbundle failed.</Data>
   </Item>
 </Results>
 ...........
```

Anyone who has an idea to what the problem can be ??

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to know if your package is fine, run the ps1 installation script (found on the folder where your appx was created) using powershell, if it is fine the next test is installing the Appx using PowerShell by using  `Add-AppxPackage` ([docu here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps)), but use as location the URL of your server, if the appx cannot be installed it could be cause the download process is not working well, since the device requests (on the http header) a range of bytes to be downloaded and your server might not be reponding properly the range of bytes.

Remember to install the Appx's certificate in the device, or if you can sign it with a valid certificate.

Good luck